# Codeigniter query from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently made a website controlled by a database, and I want to make an admin panel for it. How do I make a SQL query from a view? Maybe via a model? I haven't used a model before btw...

Comment: You don't. That goes against everything MVC architecture is about. You perform your code in the controller and/or model, and you use that data in the view.

Answer (score 2):

I don't why you have to query in view, but as far as I know it is not recommended (I don't know if it is even possible). But how about calling the function that does the query (which is from the **model**) from the **controller**, then store the results on a variable then pass them to the **view** for printing via foreach.

**MODEL**

```
function query($query){
   return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function index(){
   $data['results'] = $this->modelName->query($myQuery);
   $this->load->view('viewName', $data);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<html>
    foreach($results as $result){
        //echo every column of your table
    }
</html>
```

Comment: Nono. I've figured out how to do that. I wan't to do an UPDATE query based on information from my view, inputs in a form :)

Comment: Easy, you'll just have to fetch those values by $_POST['fieldName'] then do the thing you want to do ;)

This is actually done to the 'controller/functionName' where functionName is where your form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You would load data from the database into a model and pass the model to the view. The view would then post back to the controller with a modified version of the model and the controller would then modify the database.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html